# Abstracting Pins and Ports - Using Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, avr

I am working on a embedded project trying to learn some of the ins and outs of programming an embedded board. As one might have guessed, this involves writing code in C. I am not having too much trouble getting the grasp of setting things up correctly (in terms of ports/pins/etc..) but I am looking to abstract some of my code to make it a bit more readable.

For example, the following code turns on a Green LED that is on the board:

```
// Required CPU Speed Define
#define F_CPU 16000000

// Include the necissary library header files
#include <avr/io.h>

int main() {
     DDRD |= (1 << DDD5);
     PORTD |= (1 << PD5);

     PORTD ^= (1 << PD5);

     for(;;) { }    
}
```

On the other hand, I can `#define` the names of the ports so they are more clear, but that doesn't seem like the ideal solution (and it's unfortunately the method that I am currently using).

I would like to abstract some of the setting/functionality of enabling the on board leds (which I eventually hope to extend to other concepts such as timers/interrupts/etc..).

**How do I use Struct/Pointers to properly abstract this?**

I am currently trying the following method, but it is falling flat, and the LED is failing to turn on:

```
OnBoardLED.h

typedef struct {
    unsigned int dataDirectionRegister;
    unsigned int portNumber;
    unsigned int pinNumber;
} OnBoardLED;

void setDataDirectionRegister(OnBoardLED* led, unsigned int DDR);
void setPortNumber(OnBoardLED* led, unsigned int port);
void setPinNumber(OnBoardLED* led, unsigned int pin);

void turnOn(OnBoardLED* led);
void turnOff(OnBoardLED* led);
```

and

```
main.c

#include "inc/OnBoardLED.h"

int main(void) {
    OnBoardLED greenLED;
    setDataDirectionRegister(&greenLED, DDRD);
    setPortNumber(&greenLED, PORTD);
    setPinNumber(&greenLED, 5);

    turnOn(&greenLED);

    for(;;) { }
}
```

I know that I should be using pointers in this instance, specifically for the Data Direction Registers and the Port (so that I am properly referencing that memory location), but I do not know how to properly reference them.

What am I missing here?

Note: If needed I will post my current implementations of each function, defined in OnBoardLED.c

Edit:

```
OnBoardLED.c

#include "inc/OnBoardLED.h"

void setDataDirectionRegister(OnBoardLED* led, unsigned int DDR) {
    led->dataDirectionRegister = DDR;
}

void setPortNumber(OnBoardLED* led, unsigned int port) {
    led->portNumber = port;
}

void setPinNumber(OnBoardLED* led, unsigned int pin) {
    led->pinNumber = pin;
}

void turnOn(OnBoardLED* led) {
    led->dataDirectionRegister |= (1 << led->pinNumber);
    led->portNumber |= (1 << led->pinNumber);

    led->portNumber ^= (1 << led->pinNumber);
}
```

Comment: Having the implementation would be handy, since if it's not working then we can't tell much without seeing the code.

Comment: @Jack Code has been added to the post, thanks for taking a look

Comment: Given my limited experience with the AVR, but extensive experience with other applications on bare bones CPUs...   1) the code will not work, as written.   2) writing such code (other than the `turnon()` function just clutters the name space and makes it more difficult for the programmer to properly handle all the new/mostly undocumented API.   3) even the function `turnon()` needs a significant re-write to work properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not too much practical with AVR toolchain but from what I remember and understand things like `DDRD` are macro which map addresses from address space to register of the CPU.

So by inspecting the source code you obtain something like:

```
#define __SFR_OFFSET 0
#define _MMIO_BYTE(mem_addr) (*(volatile uint8_t *)(mem_addr))
#define _SFR_IO8(io_addr) _MMIO_BYTE((io_addr) + __SFR_OFFSET)
#define DDRD _SFR_IO8(0x0A)
```

This means that replacing `DDRD` yields something like:

```
*(volatile uint8_t*)((0x0A) + 0)
```

which is a smart macro, when used as a left-hand operand allows you to store a value at that memory address, when used as a right-hand operand you can read the value of the register. But this is still a macro and macros can hide evil details like in this situation.

What happens is that your code is

```
led->dataDirectionRegister = *(volatile uint8_t*)((0x0A) + 0);
led->dataDirectionRegister |= (1 << led->pinNumber);
```

so what you are doing is just saving the value of the data direction register into the struct member and then overwrite it with the value you would like to save into the register. So nothing basically happens.

What you need is to save the address of the data direction register to be able to dereference it later when calling the `turnOn` method. This is easily accomplished by having a member declared as

```
volatile uint8_t* dataDirectionRegister;
```

So that you can do

```
void setDataDirectionRegister(OnBoardLED* led, volatile uint8_t* DDR) {
  led->dataDirectionRegister = DDR;
}
```

and invoke it as `setDataDirectionRegister(&led, &DDRD);`. Notice the `&` operator used to obtain the address of the memory location of the register.

But now you have an address so in your `turnOn` method you must dereference the variable to store data into it:

```
void turnOn(OnBoardLED* led) {
  *led->dataDirectionRegister |= (1 << led->pinNumber);
  ...
```

So let's make a [concrete example](http://ideone.com/Z6x3xc) to show you the problem and how to fix it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#define __SFR_OFFSET 0
#define _MMIO_BYTE(mem_addr) (*(volatile uint8_t *)(&buffer[0] + mem_addr))
#define _SFR_IO8(io_addr) _MMIO_BYTE((io_addr) + __SFR_OFFSET)
#define DDRD _SFR_IO8(0x0A) 

uint8_t buffer[256];

int main(void) {
    memset(&buffer[0], 0, 256);
    DDRD = 0x40;
    printf("value: %x\n", (int)DDRD);
    *(volatile uint8_t*)(&buffer[0] + (0x0A + 0)) = 0x41;
    printf("value: %x\n", (int)DDRD);

    // now let's do what you are doing in your struct
    unsigned int dataDirectionRegister = DDRD; // value of register is copied into variable
    dataDirectionRegister = 0x80; // variable is changed but not real register
    printf("register: %x, variable: %x\n", (int)DDRD, dataDirectionRegister);

    // you must save an address to do what you need
    volatile uint8_t* realDataDirectionRegister = &DDRD;
    *realDataDirectionRegister = 0x80;
    printf("register: %x, variable: %x\n", (int)DDRD, (int)*realDataDirectionRegister);


    return 0;
}
```

Mind that I used a `buffer` as my fake memory space, since you don't have a flat memory model free to use like in a x86 architecture like you have in a microcontroller.

Comment: Thanks Jack! This actually worked perfectly, and it helped clear my confusion on some of these concepts. I knew I was heading down the right path, just didn't quite understand how to get there. Those macros hold some of the dirty details for sure.